# excell vba does not show x axis labels

Tags: vba, excel, graph

I have a sub that creates an `xlXYScatterLines` graph and populates it.

```
Set pippo = cht.Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries

pippo.Values = _
Worksheets(questoFoglio).Range(...)

pippo.Name = _
Worksheets(questoFoglio).Range(...)

pippo.XValues = _
Worksheets(questoFoglio).Range(...)
```

Then, if I select the graph and open the data selection window, I see that each serie contains the correct values (given by the `XValues` command), but when I see the graph, it doesn't show them, but 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.... how can I change it to show the given values?

Thanks in advance for any help you are able to provide,
Lorenzo from Rome